# can't connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation

I have a problem installing mysql 5.5.20 on my ubuntu 11.10. after "ps -e | grep mysql" I found mysqld_safe and mysqld is running, but it is not right when I try to connect to the server, the error is like this:

---

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

---

I have check the /etc/my.cnf which locate the mysql.sock in /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, and the access right of that folder is:

---

drwxrwxr-x  2 mysql         mysql         4096 2012-01-17 01:54 mysql

---

after "find mysql.sock" I found it in /var/run/mysql, it is really confusing
any help will be appreciated, many thanks~

Comment: Sounds like you may have an instance of mysql that didn't close properly perhaps. Have you restarted that server yet? Is this a fresh installation? Have you made any recent changes?

Comment: BTW, since this looks more like a server issue, you might want to try serverfault. stackoverflow tends to be more about programming/development issues.

Answer (score 0):

Often that error message can mean something wrong at an application level, rather than with MySQL.

Open Terminal and attempt to connect to MySQL.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Press `Enter`, then enter your password and hit `Enter` again. Once you’re in, use `SHOW DATABASES` to find out what databases are available and if the one you’re trying to connect to is there.